# ASP.Net Core "id" position in route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have a very specific way that I need to handle routing to areas and controllers.
The way that I have it setup is:

There is a "Dash" and "Servers" areas, both have "Home" and "Index" routes.
The Dash is a normal route mapped with:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Dash",
  template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
```

And it works fine with the url `/Dash/Home/Index`

The problem is with the "Servers" route, I'd like to have that "id" parameter after the area name, so that it turns out to be: `/Servers/1234/Home/Index` and still work with generating links with `@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "Servers", id = 1234 })`
I've tried mapping it as:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Server",
  template: "{area}/{id}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"
);
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. The page doesn't load on url `/Servers/1234` and the Url.Action tries to make `/Servers/Home/Index/1234` which isn't what I need...

I've also tried keeping "id" where it was and adding another parameter as "serverID" so that it looks like `template: "{area}/{serverID}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"` and making id in Url.Action to be serverID, which also doesn't work. It tries to make the link `/Servers/?serverID=1234`

I don't quite understand the routing and how to make this work, so any help with explaining it would be appreciated.
Is it possible to make that "id" be after the area name, and how would I read it inside controllers? Could there also still be a normal id that I could use in CRUD so that a url like `/Servers/1234/Info/Edit/4` could still be valid and I can know both values serverID: 1234 and id: 4?

Comment: your desired patterns should work. Your description about the problem however is unclear to me. To test it, simply try accessing the URL (but you said like you're trying to generate the URL). Finally make sure your area's controllers have `AreaAttribute` applied.

Comment: Can you share the order in which the routes are mapped in route table? What does it mean by `doesnt work`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya By "doesn't work" means that accessing that url returns 404
Here is how I have routes mapped: https://pastebin.com/uW4qWB1b

Comment: @KingKing They do have the area attribute, I've tried with accessing the url myself, what I think should be correct (/Servers/1234/) but that returns 404, is there any special stuff I need to write in the controllers for it to register that properly? I just have an almost empty controller with just Index IActionResult which returns View()

Comment: Oooooh I just noticed... I was trying "Servers" with s, it should be "Server"... well...
Still doesn't explain why generating it with Url.Action() doesn't work properly, how would I get that working?

Comment: @AleksaDjordjic do you mean now accessing the URL works but `Url.Action()` does not generate the desired URL? if so you should update your question with the code you try with `Url.Action()`

Comment: It technically does work, I've made my final route "{area}/{serverID}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}", and /Server/1234 resolves correctly, I can read the 1234 and /Server/1234/Home/Index does too. The thing is Url.Action() generates the url as /Server?serverID=1234, instead of /Server/1234, it still works, its just not the URL I want it to be

Comment: @KingKing Commented at the same time, it does work, its not in a format that I'm trying to make it to be, Url.Action code: @Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "Server", serverID = 1234 })

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using net core you better use attribute route mapping like this:

```
 
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
         endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
            name: "Server",
            areaName: "Servers",
            pattern: "Servers/{id}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}";

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
);
```

or can use conventional routing:

```
 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "MyAreas",
  pattern: "{area:exists}/{id}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}";
```

and you will have to map your controllers:

```
[Area("MyArea")]
public class MyController : Controller
```